# Program keeps looping - C++

Tags: c++

The following program does not work properly. It is supposed to be a calculation game which should not loop over and over. I'm not exactly sure what's going on. I tried rearranging some things but that did not help. I noticed that after the user inputs the numbers and answers the question, it just goes to mainMenu even though it should go to display.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

//Declaration Statement
double num1;
double num2;
double answer;
int choice;


void pauseProgram()
{
     printf("\nPress any key to continue...");
     getchar();
}

//Function Title
void title(char * programTitle)
{
     int len = strlen(programTitle);
     system("cls");
     printf("\n");
     for(int i=1; i<40 - len/2;i++) printf(" ");
     printf("%s\n",programTitle);
}

void intro()
{
    title("Calculation Game");
    printf("\nThis program will test your math abilites");

    pauseProgram();
}

void userInput()
{
    title("Calculation Game");
    printf("\nPlease enter positive numbers only\n");

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%lf",&num1);
    getchar();

    printf("Enter another number:");
    scanf("%lf",&num2);
    getchar();

    printf("What is %lf + %lf?",num1,num2);
    scanf("%lf",&answer);

    if (num1<0 or num2<0)
    {
        printf("\nSorry, you must enter a positive value! Please try again.");
        userInput();
        pauseProgram();
    }

}

void display()
{

    title("Calculation Game");
    if (answer=num1+num2)
        printf("\nWow you got the right answer\n");
    else if (answer!=num1+num2)
        printf("\nHmmm...maybe we should review this math concept again!\n");

    pauseProgram();

}

void goodbye()
{
    title("Calculation Game");

    printf("\nFor further information call: 1-800-123-4567\n"); 

    pauseProgram();
}


void mainMenu()
{
    title("Calculation Game");
    printf("\n1.\tPlay Game");
    printf("\n2.\tExit\n");
    printf("\nEnter 1 or 2:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    getchar();

    if (choice==1)
        userInput();
    if (choice=2)
        goodbye();

    if (choice!=1 or choice!=2);
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter either 1 or 2! Please try again.");
        mainMenu();
    }
}

//Main program
int main()
{
    do
    {   

        intro();
        mainMenu();
        userInput();
        if (answer==num1+num2 or answer!=num1+num2)
        {

            display();
        }

    }while(1); 
goodbye();
}
```

Comment: Well, as you can probably see, the main program enters a `do{ ... } while(1)` loop which never ends. Where should the program end ? You should have a break somewhere !

Comment: @Magix the program should end after goodbye, i tried putting a break after goodbye but that didnt work

Comment: The program will not go to function display, it just goes to goodbye after userinput. Not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentionned in my comment, you can probably see the `main()` function enters an infinite loop:

```
do {
    ...
} while (1)
```

This loop will not stop until told so. For instance, you can tell the program to exit in your `pauseProgram()` function :

```
void pauseProgram()
{
     printf("\nPress any key to continue...");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
}
```

or in your `goodbye()` function :

```
void goodbye()
{
    title("Calculation Game");

    printf("\nGame designed by David Liubart\n");   
    printf("\nFor further information call: 1-800-123-4567\n"); 

    pauseProgram();
    exit(0);
}
```

Finally, you could use a `break` instruction anywhere in the loop in order to exit the loop.

Comment: thanks, i tried the exit(0) and it worked but now I still have a problem where it goes to goodbye right after userinput, im not sure why its doing that

Comment: probably because `userInput` calls `pauseProgram`, where you exit the program ? Also, if your question is solved, please mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: nope, i tried taking out pauseprogram but still same thing. the program doesnt even go to display

Comment: Well you should open another question with everything needed to diagnose the problem. This is off-topic for this thread ;-)

Comment: it wont let me :-(

Comment: "It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just do your best to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 2 days!"